# Confidence region with minimal volume

Tags: r, algorithm, probability

Let X be an n-dimensional gaussian random variable with a given covariance matrix. I'm looking for the rectangular confidence region with minimal volume. That is, I would like to compute a vector M=(M_1, M_2, ..., M_n) such that the region (-M,M) has minimal minimal volume, under the constraint that the integral of the gaussian pdf over that region is equal to a given value alpha.

Is there an R function that computes that (or possibly a C++ library that I can import)?

Comment: Could you please clarify which region you are integrating over? When you say "such that the region (-M, M) has minimal volume" I understand a line segment connecting the point -M to the point M, but at another point you say that your desired region is "rectangular"... Do you mean the region containing all points (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) such that x_i is between -M_i and M_i?

Comment: sorry if it's not completely clear, but I didn't know how to do it without being able to write maths. I also posted it on MO, hope it is clearer there: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/169022/minimal-rectangular-confidence-regions